# Magento 2 Site after moving from local server to live all pages showing 404 except Home page?

Tags: magento2, admin, category, frontend, 404-page

After moving My Magento 2 website from local server to Production server All the Pages including admin showing/redirecting 404 page except Home Page.

How Can I resolve this issue ?

Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Try to enable mod_rewrite and check it.

Comment: ok, will do it now.

Comment: Check is URL rewriting is working, is it mod_rewrite enable?

Answer (score 1):

That happens typically when `mod_rewrite` is not enabled. It could be that it's not installed but it's more likely that your host config file is not properly setup. Check this [link](http://tymonn.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache2-debianubuntu/) for a reference.